# Rails - ArgumentError in UsersController#create - too few arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, arguments

This is probably really basic but I can't seem to figure it out.

Essentially, when I try to create a new user using a form, and the user details are already present and not unique, I receive he following error:

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#create

too few arguments

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:61:in `format'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:61:in `create'
```

Here's my `create` action in my `user_controller.rb`:

```
  # POST /users
  # POST /users.xml
  def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])

        if @user.save
          flash[:notice] = 'User successfully created' and redirect_to :action=>"index"
        else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

And here's my `user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  validates :email, :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

Here's also my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :email %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.input :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact layout of the code has changed a bit through different rails version (please post what version you are using - check the Gemfile).

This example is for rails 3+ (it was generated using 3.2.5 but should apply to all 3+ or at least 3.1+ versions)

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Blob was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

p.s. Good choice with simple_form, it makes life MUCH easier!

Comment: Yes, that was the `respond_to` block I was talking about. The "exact layout" doesn't matter, though--there's no reason not to just use what the OP already had.

Comment: Thankyou! :D I knew it was a simple thing haha

BTW i'm using Rails 3.2

Answer (score 6):

What's `format` in this case?

There's no `respond_to` block, put it back in! You're referencing some other `format`.